# Is there a way to duplicate Word pages using VBA from Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm trying to specify the number of times the first page of a word document is duplicated from an Excel vba code. But i keep getting an error message.

I am basically trying to always select the first page of the document and copying it at the end of the document. And repeat the same process the amount of times defined by the user in a worksheet cell.

The relevant code is this one:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Interceramic") 'Elección de la hoja de cálculo'
Dim objword As Object
Set objword = CreateObject("Word.Application") 'Declaración y configuración de la aplicación word'
objword.Visible = True
objword.Documents.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\interceramic_base.docx" 'Elección del documento de word base'

Dim paginas As Integer

paginas = ws.Range("N1").Value

For i = 1 To paginas
    objword.Selection.Goto what:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToPrevious, Name:="1"
    objword.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\Page").Range.Copy
    objword.Selection.Goto what:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToNext, Count:=-1
    objword.Selection.Paste
Next
```

The error that keeps popping out is: "Error '4608': Error defined by the application or the object".

I really don't know what's wrong with the code and I have exhausted all the info I could find about this.

Edit for future reference:
I tried the solutions explaines by other users to no avail. But I solved this problem changing the code to this:

```
Dim objword As Word.Application
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Interceramic") 'Elección de la hoja de cálculo'
Set objword = CreateObject("Word.Application") 'Declaración y configuración de la aplicación word'
objword.Visible = True
objword.Documents.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\interceramic_base.docx" 'Elección del documento de word base'

Dim pags As Variant

pags = ws.Range("N1").Value - 1
For i = 1 To pags
    With objword
        .ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\Page").Select
        .Selection.Copy
        .Selection.EndKey unit:=wdStory
        .Selection.InsertNewPage
        .Selection.Paste
    End With
Next
```

Comment: If you are late-binding, then `wdGoToPage`, `wdGoToPrevious`, and `wdGoToNext` are undefined.

Comment: Which line raises the error? "\Page" is not a valid bookmark name.

Comment: @JohnKorchok - "\Page" is a perfectly valid bookmark name. It is one of the [predefined bookmarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/Concepts/Miscellaneous/predefined-bookmarks)

Comment: Perhaps when Word creates it. A user-created bookmark called \Page only gets you "The bookmark name is not valid."

Answer (score 1):

You are using late binding so Excel doesn't understand what `wdGoToPage`, `wdGoToPrevious`, or `wdGoToNext` mean. You need to use their values instead:

- wdGoToPage = 1
- wdGoToNext = 2
- wdGoToPrevious = 3

However, there is a better way to achieve this which avoids use of both the `Selection` object and the clipboard.

```
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Interceramic") 'Elección de la hoja de cálculo'
   Dim objword As Object
   Set objword = CreateObject("Word.Application") 'Declaración y configuración de la aplicación word'
   objword.Visible = True
   Dim objDoc As Object
   Set objDoc = objword.Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\interceramic_base.docx")  'Elección del documento de word base'

   Dim paginas As Integer

   paginas = ws.Range("N1").Value
   Dim rng As Object
   Set rng = objDoc.Content
   rng.Collapse 1 'wdCollapseStart

   For i = 1 To paginas
      With objDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range
         .InsertParagraphAfter
         .FormattedText = rng.Bookmarks("\Page").Range.FormattedText
      End With
   Next
```

EDIT:

Your document contains only a table. The bulk of what you see as the first page is in the header. You cannot duplicate that page by copying and pasting.

I assume that your purpose in duplicating the page is to create a number of related "documents". If that is the case you should save that document as a template (.dotx) and either use it to create separate documents, or, if you need to populate the documents with data from a workbook, as a mail merge template.

EDIT 2:

The following code has been tested on your document and is working in O365 without errors.

NOTE: I do not recommend this method as it is not good practice. You should always create documents from a template. If you are looking to create multiple documents (invoices?) from Excel data your best option is to use Mail Merge.

```
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Interceramic") 'Elección de la hoja de cálculo'
   Dim objword As Object
   Set objword = CreateObject("Word.Application") 'Declaración y configuración de la aplicación word'
   objword.Visible = True
   Dim objDoc As Object
   Set objDoc = objword.Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\interceramic_base.docx")  'Elección del documento de word base'

   Dim paginas As Integer

   paginas = ws.Range("N1").Value
   Dim rng As Object
   Set rng = objDoc.Content
   rng.Collapse 1 'wdCollapseStart
   rng.Bookmarks("\Page").Range.Copy

   Dim i As Integer
   For i = 1 To paginas
      With objDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range
         .InsertBreak 7 'wdPageBreak
         .InsertParagraphAfter
         .Paste
      End With
   Next
```

Comment: On which line did you get the error, and what is the text of the error? In common with most people I don't have error codes committed to memory.

Comment: I guess it has something to do with the fact that my word document has no paragraphs per se, but a bunch of text boxes?

I'm gonna paraphrase here, because the error is in Spanish: Runtime error '5937' ocurred: Error defined by the application or the object". It doesn't specify in which line I got the error :/ or how can I know this?

Comment: @RodolfoBarrientosAcosta - step through the code line by line.

Comment: @RodolfoBarrientosAcosta - that sounds like a very poorly constructed document, but it will still contain a minimum of 1 paragraph.

Comment: The error pops in the line 'FormattedText = rng.Bookmarks("\Page").Range.FormattedText'

Comment: To avoid lots of questions about the document are you able to upload a copy somewhere and provide a link?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1oS5j8RemgUzDpHYXjM1hFWy8hbCfSiPH?usp=sharing

Comment: Move the .InsertParagraphAfter command to before the loop or possible after depending on exactly what you are transferring. It is including to insure there is an open paragraph upon which to transfer the data. Including it at the top of the loop is what is causing the problem because it changes what is the last paragraph of the document.

Comment: @RodolfoBarrientosAcosta - please see edited answer.

Comment: @RichMichaels - sorry but you are completely incorrect. The `.InsertParagraphAfter` needs to be in the loop to create an empty paragraph in which to add the formatted text, though in this instance it won't work because of the layout of the document.

Comment: @Timothy Rylatt - well my testing of your code showed differently. I receive the 5937 error  when the InsertParagraphAfter command is there. I tested with a document that contains many paragraphs of existing text. The error is “Cannot Copy Content Between these Two Ranges."

Comment: @RichMichaels - in my testing, on a document with 3 pages of existing text, it runs without errors.

Comment: @RodolfoBarrientosAcosta - now that I have had time to test with your document I have updated my answer. Please see second edit.    NOTE: Using text boxes and wrapped tables is not good practice. Your document could very easily be constructed using inline objects without compromising the layout and formatting.